# Make Laravel Model Authenticatable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-authentication, laravel-10

I want a different Model the be able to login too.

The name of the Model is **Client**.

So this is added this to `auth.php` config:

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'client' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'clients',
    ],
],

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],

    'clients' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Client::class,
    ],
],
```

And expected that this should work:
`Auth::guard('client')->loginUsingId($client->id, true);`

But this doesn't show any Authenticated Client:
`return Auth::guard('client')->user();`

What am I missing?

Routes are like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:client']], function () {     
   Route::get('my-orders', [OrderController::class, 'index']); //goes to login route });
```

This is the login code:

```
Auth::guard('client')->loginUsingId($client->id, true); 
ray(['Auth' => Auth::guard('client')->user()]); // Shows correct Auth
return redirect()->to("/{$locale}/my-orders"); // Re-redirects to Login route
```

Comment: This configuration looks correct, is the user logging in with a form or is this all internal? Is the user authenticated with both guards at once? Does `Auth::user()` show what you'd expect?

Comment: @miken32 Authenticated once. Hardcoded via the `loginUsingId()`. The `Auth::user()` is blank. Think I'm missing maybe some `use` things in the Model? So it's known the Model is Authenticatable..?

Comment: Well you haven't shown us the model code. Did you compare with your `User` model?

Comment: Just to confirm, `$client->id` exists in the database right? This won't work with new model instances until you've saved them

Comment: Yes, I exists. @apokryfos - It's an existing user. Only thing is, that I'm using ULID's.. Thats the thing maybe? That's the only changes from a default Model i have

Comment: Since navigating to a new page involves a completely new independent request, I believe the request is treated as a new session. More information is needed to detect the problem, but it is certain that for some reason, when a new HTTP request is made, your previous session ends, and you receive a new one. Is session handling properly configured? (I assume that your LoginController, login route, and Client Model are correct. Unfortunately, you haven't shared them.)

Comment: Make sure you have implemented the ULID's properly:
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#uuid-and-ulid-keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're  using auth in  another model you have to **use `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable` interface and `Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable` trait**

Example

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Client extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract
{
    use Authenticatable;

}
```

then

```
php artisan config:cache
```

---

after that, these will work

```
Auth::guard('client')->loginUsingId($client->id, true)
Auth::guard('client')->user()
```

---

> Make sure you've required columns `email` or `username` and `password` and `remember_token`

---

**Edit 01**

In `redirectIfAuthenticated`(located in `app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php`)

add this

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
{
    $guards = empty($guards) ? [null] : $guards;

    foreach ($guards as $guard) {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            switch ($guard) {
                case 'client':
                    return redirect(route('client.dashboard'));
                default:
                    return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
            }
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

> Updating middleware to be aware of the new guard.

Comment: Hi, Thanks! Tried that, but keeps redirecting me to the default login-route.

`Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:client']], function () {
    Route::get('my-orders', [OrderController::class, 'index']); // goes to login route
});`

Comment: `Auth::guard('client')->loginUsingId($client->id, true);`
`ray(['Auth' => Auth::guard('client')->user()]); // Shows correct Auth! `
`return redirect()->to("/{$locale}/my-orders"); // Re-redirects to Login route`

Comment: @user1469734 use the above code structure by removing all other what you tried and add **Edit 01** as well

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the default auth in Laravel with more than one model and more than one guard
to make a set of steps

Here are some details ..

1 - You must first add more than one guard
from file "config/auth.php"

Indeed, you did this step, so I will not explain it

2 - You must specify guard in model

using the protected $guard = "guard_name"

And use the auth trait

and implement auth interface

3 - You have to make some changes to the

"LoginController" in this place "app/Http/Controllers/Auth"

4 - You should also do some modifications to the

"RegisterController" in this place "app/Http/Controllers/Auth"

5 - You must specify the place where the person who registers will go after registration, based on the gurd, if it is the control panel or the home page

By default it is the home page

6 - You have to modify the middleware
also
From this place

"RedirectIfAuthenticated.php"

7 - You may also need to modify the handler class
From this place

"app/Exceptions/Handler.php"

8 - And of course you have to modify the views

9 - You may also need to modify the route

I think that's all you need

Here are some references to know what needs to be modified in the code with an example

https://techvblogs.com/blog/multiple-authentication-guards-laravel-9

Answer (score -1):

There might be a few reasons why is NOT authenticating using the `client guard`:

- **The request is not authenticated at all**. This could be because the
  user has not logged in, or because the request is using an
  unauthorized method, such as `GET`.
- **The request is authenticated using a different guard**. This could be
  because the user is logged in using a different guard, such as `web`.

So, verify that the current request is authenticated using the `client guard`, with this method:

```
auth()->guard('client')->check()
```

Is the user Authenticated? Returns:

```
true (1) OR false (0)
```

To force it use:

```
$user = User::find(1);

if (auth()->guard('client')->login($user)) {
// The user is now logged in using the `client` guard.
} else {
// The login failed.
}
```

This would give you a good idea of why is failing. I hope it helps!